# How to make ruamel.yaml dump formatted numpy arrays as simple list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ruamel.yaml

I'd like to have ruamel.yaml dump out a numpy array (1-D, 2-D, or n-D) but I'd like it to be formatted in a nice legible way. I know there are a number of similar questions, but even with those, I haven't been able to solve this. Ideally it would look something like this that looks like

```
data:
  oneD: 
    [0.44, 0.49, 0.73, 0.46, 0.12, 0.98, 0.91, 0.5 , 0.1 , 0.26, 0.89, 0.02, 0.51]
  twoD: 
    [[0.44, 0.49, 0.73, 0.46, 0.12, 0.98, 0.91, 0.5 ],
     [0.11, 0.4 , 0.51, 0.71, 0.27, 0.47, 0.1 , 0.74],
     [0.36, 0.56, 0.85, 0.02, 0.93, 0.19, 0.72, 0.96]]
  threeD: 
    [[[0.17, 0.46, 0.9 ],
      [0.75, 0.97, 0.32],
      [0.95, 0.39, 0.26]],

     [[0.06, 0.3 , 0.23],
      [0.78, 0.14, 0.89],
      [0.47, 0.72, 0.02]]]
```

I tried to accomplish this with numpy's handy array2string function and registering a new representer for the ndarray form, shown here:

```
def numpyRepresenter(dumper, data):
    asStr = np.array2string(data, formatter={'float_kind':lambda x: "%.3f" % x}, separator=', ', threshold=int(1e10), max_line_width=120)
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', asStr, style='|')
```

Which worked quite well, except for now they are treated as strings and when reading them back in, they get interpreted as such.

I have also tried just simply having the representer convert the np arrays to lists and printing those out but the formatting isn't as nice, or as clear especially with data with different decimal places.

Is this possible to do with ruamel or is there a better approach that I should be using?

Full MWE here

```
import numpy as np
import ruamel.yaml

def numpyRepresenter(dumper, data):
    asStr = np.array2string(data, formatter={'float_kind':lambda x: "%.2f" % x}, separator=', ', threshold=int(1e10), max_line_width=120)
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', asStr, style='|')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

test = yaml.load("""
data:
  oneD: 
    [0.44, 0.49, 0.73, 0.46, 0.12, 0.98, 0.91, 0.5 , 0.1 , 0.26, 0.89, 0.02, 0.51]
  twoD: 
    [[0.44, 0.49, 0.73, 0.46, 0.12, 0.98, 0.91, 0.5 ],
     [0.11, 0.4 , 0.51, 0.71, 0.27, 0.47, 0.1 , 0.74],
     [0.36, 0.56, 0.85, 0.02, 0.93, 0.19, 0.72, 0.96]]
  threeD: 
    [[[0.17, 0.46, 0.9 ],
      [0.75, 0.97, 0.32],
      [0.95, 0.39, 0.26]],

     [[0.06, 0.3 , 0.23],
      [0.78, 0.14, 0.89],
      [0.47, 0.72, 0.02]]]
""")

oneD = 5*np.array(test['data']['oneD'])
twoD = np.array(test['data']['twoD'])**(2/3)
threeD = np.sqrt(np.array(test['data']['threeD']))

test['data']['oneD'] = oneD
test['data']['twoD'] = twoD
test['data']['threeD'] = threeD

yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.default_style = None
yaml.representer.add_representer(np.ndarray, numpyRepresenter)
with open('testOut.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(test, fp)
```

Comment: `arr.tolist()` is the fastest, most general way of creating a list from an array.  I suspect such lists are the best format for writing to `yaml` and reloading.  However as you've found lists do not line up columns nicely.  You might want to look at the code for `np.savetxt` to see how it formats arrays as neat rows/columns.  The key is it creates format string and does `fmt%tuple(row)`, for each `row` of a 2d array.

Comment: represent_scalar is not the way to go. I would tend to write out a tagged YAML construct and in the representer construct a special list of `CommentedSeq` items that contain `ScalarFloat`s. The special list should then do the line wrapping. BTW it makes little sense to load with the round-trip-loader and then set the `.default_flow_style` attribute as the individual `CommentedSeq/Map` contain flow information in their `.fa` attribute.

Comment: I think I understand the concept, but I can't quite figure out how to implement it. Is your suggestion that I'd be able to keep to formatting as i like it by dumping it as a comment? I so far haven't been able to figure out what tag to issue to convince the dumper to treat it as a comment

P.S. thank you for ruamel.yaml! it has worked great for me for many years.